# MHT sending mail with Indy

Tags: delphi, indy, mhtml

My question is how to send a mht message throw Indy 9 with Delphi 7 IDE?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have already saw this link but I thought that this is not a mht mail message. Is this a mht message sending way with Indy 9?

Comment: Could you give me some example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MHT is a format for saving an HTML document and associated resources into a single file. To send such a document as an email, you would have to extract the HTML and resource data first and put them into a TIdMessage component like other HTML-formatted email.  There are articles on Indy's website for how to send HTML emails with Indy.

Have a look at [RFC 2557](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2557.txt) for how MHTML interacts with email.